# Honda Civic 1997 should the car be on or off when bleeding the brakes?

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, bleeding

Black four door Honda Civic 1997. Brake go straight to the floor.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally bleed the brakes with the car off for safety reasons, but could be done with either engine running or not.